# select onchange local storage not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage, background-color, onchange

I found similar Question but answers were with Jquery or not working in this particular case.
i have the following HTML code

```
<html>
<body onload="load()">
<div>
    <select id="colorlist" onchange="saveSelect()">
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="#E0C2FF">#E0C2FF</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="purple">Purple</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the following javascript code which works in Chrome but not in Firefox (I didn't test in IE yet).

```
function saveSelect () {
    localStorage.bgColor = document.getElementById("colorlist").value;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgColor; 
}
function load() {
    if (localStorage.bgColor.length == 0) {
        localStorage.bgColor = "white";
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgColor;
        document.getElementById("colorlist").value = localStorage.bgColor;
    }
}
```

If you know a good solution for Firefox or possibly for all Browsers in HTML, CSS or the best would be in Javascript (please no Library like Jquery), i would be thankful.

Sugestions by Freez

http://jsfiddle.net/4a60k1vm/

sometimes it works sometimes not.

Comment: Other than the length check, it works fine in my Firefox. Replace the length check with just `if ( !localStorage.bgColor ) ... `

Comment: i dont realy understand what u mean/want or how it will help, sorry. If you please could explain yourself?

Comment: okay i edited it - it stil dont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
localStorage.setItem('bgColor', x);
```

Instead of

```
localStorage.bgColor = x;
```

And

```
localStorage.getItem('bgColor');
```

To retrieve value of you stored.

Firefox will not crash anymore because it's the right way to use localStorage.

Comment: seems like an easy way, that i dont come to right just away....
i tried it but it didnt realy work, but i edited it as a sugestion

Comment: I have edited your post with the good syntax, I think. See my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4a60k1vm/1/)

Comment: how does this work? how is the If else thing loaded? it needs a load function, am I right?

Comment: however as edited in my opost, it works in chorme as the code I posted but not in Firefox

Comment: I tried in Firefox and it works... See my edit in the edit history or test my fiddle with Firefox you'll see [http://jsfiddle.net/4a60k1vm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/4a60k1vm/1/)

Comment: Are you using an old version of FF? Open your console and check for errors.

Comment: hm your code realy dont work but with a few reinstalations and a restart my complete Porgramm wich contains your code now works perfectly. This is wierd, but a s long as it works ...

You have my upvote. Thx for your time and help.

Comment: found the Problem it had something to do with my Privacy Setiings.

Comment: Ok, I understand  ;) but I recommend you to use the getters and setters with localStorage

Comment: i will in every future Programm it looks better, makes more sense and is probably faster.